# Swift: runtime error crash only in release mode

Tags: swift, debugging, swiftui, runtime, release

I don't get this in debug mode, but when I switch the run mode to release mode, my phone crashes on the following line:

```
self.podcasts = PodcastsView(play: { audio in
        self.videoPlayerView.pause()
        self.showVideoPlayer = false
        self.audioPlayerView.play(audio: audio)
        self.audioCurrentlyPlaying = audio
        self.showAudioPlayer = true
        self.playBarShowing = true
    }, indentBottom: Binding(get: {
        self.playBarShowing
    }, set: {
        self.playBarShowing = $0
    }))
```

Error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff0)`

This is the initializer being called:

```
init(play: @escaping (_ audio: KHKAudio) -> Void, indentBottom: Binding<Bool>) {
    self.play = play
    self.model = PodcastsViewModel()
    self.indentBottom = indentBottom
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In the initializer being called, the 'model' is an `@ObservedObject`, not an `@StateObject`. Changing this fixed it. I don't understand why, though, and why it was only a release issue.